# How can one calculate the exact number of different outputs using threads

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

So lets say I have this following functions:
[image: Functions]

So If I run 3 different Threads that work as following:
thread 1 runs f1,thread 2 runs f2,thread 3 runs f3

How can I calculate the Maximum number of different outputs?
(You could test every possible combination of context switch but that's excessive)

I have found 12 possible outcomes:
12,10,0,20,21,6,5,1,16,11,22
So, How is it possible to know that there are a Maximum of 12 different outputs?

Comment: Please don't show pictures of code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `v` is global, you have a data race, which is undefined behavior.

Your program may crash, or output any number (not just the 12 you listed). If this is a homework question, whoever is asking it has no idea what he or she is doing.

To understand what might happen, read [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210912110157/https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/blogs/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong.html) and [this](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/25/dealing-with-benign-data-races-the-c-way/).

Comment: I'm currently studying "operating system" course and sadly this was on one of my papers, sad to hear that my professor has no idea on what he is doing :( , thanks for the help!